# Problem in decimals between api communication

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-2.2

if the title is rare, I tell you the problem that is happening to me.

I have 2 web api in net core 2.2, since api A, I call a method of api B and it returns a decimal that does not apply.

Real example (Custom event in AppInsight):
{"paymentTypeId": "1", "quoteNro": 6, "totalCost": 63831774.02} = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

The TotalCost property is like being "broken", the value you should have returned is 7443.02

Now, if I try all this locally, everything works correctly, it doesn't break the decimals, when I try it from azure, it fails.
I've tried calling API B directly from Postman to azure and it doesn't fail, it returns well.
If I try to call API A from Postman to azure that internally calls API B, it fails.

Until you find where the error originated, discard many things, for example:

The deserialization of the answer.
I use automapper and I thought there was something wrong with the profiles.
Compare the 2 DTO of the different api, both their name and type of data.
It is not a culture issue.
It is not a rounding issue (later they sent me a fairly large decimal and I was left with only 2 decimals, the last test we did was to ask them to round me the value from API B)

I remain at your disposal for any other information you want and thank you very much.

Comment: Show us the code where you call api b from api a and how do you map the results back?

Comment: var result = await this._httpClientFactory.CreateClient(httpClientName).PostAsJsonAsync(new Uri(uri), content);            var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response);  
The answer is already wrong, before deserializing

Comment: Try [Azure Web App Remote Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-dotnet-visual-studio)